# Best way to interpret HTML Response and paste on Worksheet

Tags: arrays, xml, vba, http

I have a URL that returns a ton of information that I need to break apart into rows/columns etc.

So far I have been able to get the `.responsetext` and then use `Split` to break it down, but I'm wondering best approach for getting this data onto spreadsheet as I'm about to do more "Split" and I feel like there is a better way using perhaps Arrays?

Macro:

```
Sub TEstHTML()

Dim URLStr As String
URLStr = "PrivateURL"

'<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime & Microsoft XML, V6.0
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    Dim tableCells As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

        With xhr

            .Open "GET", URLStr, False
            .send

            If .readyState = 4 And .status = 200 Then
                Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
                doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                Debug.Print doc.body.innerHTML
                Stop
            Else
                Debug.Print "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .readyState & vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .status
            End If

        End With
        
          Dim SplitArr() As String
      SplitArr = Split(doc.body.innerHTML, "{")
Debug.Print SplitArr(1)
Stop
End Sub
```

The page sends back a lot of data formatted like so:

```
 {"ClientCode":"CLICODE","ClientName":"MyClient","ContractNumber":"2021-1",...}
```

Which the Split function returns:

```
"ClientCode":"CLICODE","ClientName":"MyClient","ContractNumber":"2021-1",...
```

I need to turn this into Colum Headers `ClientCode` & `ClientName` & `ContractNumber` and then paste the values one `SplitArr(i)` at a time. Note there are many column headers I'd like this to not be hardcoded ideally, but if needed I can make the column headers and then paste information somehow.

Comment: How about: 1- Split again with "," -- 2 - split by ":", and finish off by 3 - replacing the double quotes with nothing ("").  If the split chars are not in any of the fields.

Comment: @GokhanAycan Thats kinda what I was going to do and wondered if there was a better/quicker way w/ Arrays. Were talking about triple nested SplitArrs followed by a nested for each loop. Sounds bad IMO.

Comment: Hmm, maybe just replace "," or ":" with the other making them all same, then split with whatever you got left. Then create a 2D array, one for-next loop with step 2 should be enough to populate it from the split array. Then just paste on to the range. Also, maybe RegEx can help too, but I am not really familiar with it. Someone else should chime in, or ask another question regarding that. You can evaluate performance with some timers.

Comment: That looks like JSON and the usual recommendation for parsing that is this library: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: [Example on how to use JSONConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269707/parsing-json-with-vba-json-parser), if you are not sure of the structure of the JSON, paste the JSON in [this parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to get a sense of it visually so you know how to navigate through.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not 100% my data is true JSON, but that parser definitely will work! Much better then `Split` x3 with nested `For Loops`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, or this data is/isn't JSON but this tool works great. I did have to make a function to "clean" the strings though. Here is what I ended up with..

```
Sub Testing()
 Dim URLStr As String
 URLStr = "URL"
 
 Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Set HTMLDoc = Get_HTMLDocument(URLStr)
 Dim HTMLDocStr As String
 HTMLDocStr = HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML
 HTMLDocStr = ConvertToJsonClear(HTMLDocStr)
 
 Dim SplitArr() As String, Parsed As Dictionary, k, l As Long
 SplitArr = Split(HTMLDocStr, "{")

 For X = 1 To UBound(SplitArr) Step 1
 l = 0
 HTMLDocStr = ConvertToJsonClear(SplitArr(X))
 Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(HTMLDocStr)
  For Each k In Parsed.Keys
  l = l + 1
   If X = 1 Then
    Cells(1, l).Value = k
   End If
   Cells(X + 1, l).Value = Parsed(k)
   'Debug.Print k & " = "; Parsed(k)
  Next
  'Stop
 Next X
Stop
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function ConvertToJsonClear(JSonStr As String) As String
 JSonStr = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(JSonStr)
 JSonStr = Replace(JSonStr, "[", "")
 JSonStr = Replace(JSonStr, "]", "")
 JSonStr = Replace(JSonStr, "\", "")
 
 If Left(JSonStr, 1) = Chr(34) Then
  'Stop
  JSonStr = Right(JSonStr, Len(JSonStr) - 1)
 End If
 
 If Left(JSonStr, 1) <> "{" Then
  'Stop
  JSonStr = "{" & JSonStr
 End If
 
 If Right(JSonStr, 3) = "},""" Then
  'Stop
  'Debug.Print Right(JSonStr, 3)
  'Stop
  JSonStr = Left(JSonStr, Len(JSonStr) - 2) & Chr(34)
 End If
 
 If Right(JSonStr, 1) = "," Then
  'Stop
  JSonStr = Left(JSonStr, Len(JSonStr) - 1)
 End If
 
 ConvertToJsonClear = JSonStr
 'Debug.Print ConvertToJsonClear
End Function
```

I don't have my real data in front of me, but I tackled this a home with a homemade `TestStr`. The VBA-JSON parser linked in OP Comments by @TimWilliams worked great with a bit of string manipulation. I'll have to play around with real data and perhaps clean it up, but this works for now!

```
Public Sub JsonTest()

 Dim TestStr As String, SplitArr() As String, k, I As Long
 TestStr = "{""CC"":""TestA"",""DD"":""RESA"",""ZZ"":""RESAA""},{""CC"":""TestB"",""DD"":""RESB"",""ZZ"":""RESBB""}"
 SplitArr = Split(TestStr, "{")
 
 For I = 1 To UBound(SplitArr) Step 1
 
  TestStr = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson("{" & SplitArr(I))
  TestStr = Left(TestStr, Len(TestStr) - 1)
  TestStr = Right(TestStr, Len(TestStr) - 1)
  TestStr = Replace(TestStr, "\", "")
  'Debug.Print TestStr
  'Stop
  
  Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(TestStr)
  For Each k In Parsed.Keys
   Debug.Print k & " = " & Parsed(k)
   'Stop
  Next
 Next

End Sub
```